# Syncing a table in react.js to database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, mongodb

Hi I'd like to know what is the way you would make a timetable(that's changed every week by admin) to a database for a webapp. I have searched and found nothing so anything to point to or helpful ideas are welcome! Thanks
(Note I am not experienced with databases in react(it is a school project) so the easiest way would be most helpful)

And would you recommend using mongodb for this? If so why?

Comment: I already have the table in react (using react-jsx) but not sure how to sync it or what to database type to sync it to

Comment: This is a very broad question more suitable to tutorials than SO.

Comment: I tried finding one but they were also general and not specific to this scenario will keep on searching though

Comment: _" I have searched and found nothing"_: seriously nothing? You found MDB so that isn't nothing. There are lots of solutions out there but they are all determined by your use case. Do you want an SQL DB or one like MDB that is document-based? What backend server are you using? What are your endpoints? How are you aggregating your data? Etc. Part of being a developer is looking at each product to work out how it suits your needs, and then choosing the one that closely matches. And, sadly, that takes time.

Comment: You will be able to present results from any database in React. React doesn't have to do anything with the database per se. So really what you need is a database and a database design suitable to store your timetables. There certainly are tutorials out there on this kind of stuff. What I am saying, no point searching for "React" on Google. React is just the framework you use to create a nice view for your data.